SpringBoot: Changing SmartLifecycle phase of the embedded container
My Spring application needs to wait for some computations to gracefully stop before shutting down; but I want the server to remain up to expose metrics/healthchecks API's while the computations are finishing up. By default, the embedded container's graceful shutdown is triggered before any shutdown hooks on the application component.
As suggested here, I would like to manually set the application's SmartLifecycle phase so it its stop() event is called before the web server shuts down. However, the WebServerGracefulShutdownLifecycle.SMART_LIFECYCLE_PHASE is already the maximum integer, so there doesn't seem to be a way to give a higher priority phase (stop hooks are called from largest to smallest phase). Is there any way to adjust the WebServer lifecycle phase to be a lower value to guarantee my application has a higher phase?

What version of Spring Boot are you using? In all currently supported versions (3.1.x and later) the phase is SmartLifecycle.DEFAULT_PHASE - 1024.

Oh interesting... I'm using 2.7.9. Unfortunately, not my own codebase so I'dl have to check if we could upgrade

It was changed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31714 for Spring Boot 3.0. You might, although I haven't tried or tested it, be able to get things to work with 2.7.x if you used a BeanFactoryPostProcessor to replace the graceful shutdown and start-stop beans with your own implementations with different phases.
